# Binding a resource key to a span element

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

I want to create something along the lines:

```
    <TextBlock>
      <Span DataContext="{Binding Viewmodel1}"></Span>
      <Span DataContext="{Binding Viewmodel2}"></Span>
    </TextBlock>
```

The reason I'm using *span*s is that I need seamless content wrapping.

The content of the two *span* elements must be set at runtime, preferably through a resource key. The resources will contain a collection of inline elements (text and dropdowns).

How would I go about setting the resource key onto the span? Or alternitively, could you suggest a better way?

I'm using .NET 3.5

Thank you.

Comment: I think you want a DataTemplate, but since you didn't say why you want to do something (not quite sure what) with a resource key, I could be wrong. Can you try to explain what your overall goal is? I mean, the span with a resource key is a tool to accomplish some goal. What is that goal?

Comment: I want to load plugins at runtime, and each plugin is made up of a combination of two configuration views. I want to present both configurations in a single sentence format (hence the two spans with a comma). To define the contents of the views (which are really a few inline UI elements) I was thinking of storing them as resources in a resource dictionary. *Spans* do not support DataTemplates.